# Login not working with specific browser

Tags: browser, login

Very weird issue which I have experienced twice in the past few days. For an unknown reason, logging into a certain web service does not work with one browser, but does with another. Specifically:

- **Case 1:** phpMyAdmin - able to login using FireFox, not able to login using Chrome. The service is running on a local server, and I am trying to login
  from a client on the same network. At first I thought I had forgotten
  the MySQL credentials, but after resetting the root password for
  MySQL the problem still existed. However, when I tried another
  browser (Chrome), it suddenly worked. Still doesn't work in Firefox.
- **Case 2:** Google services - able to login using Chrome and IE, not able to login using Firefox. On a freshly installed computer, with both browsers just having been installed. This is even weirder. Firefox has not been used before, has no saved passwords or anything, but still can't login. Chrome does have stored credentials, but these belong to another account. IE doesn't have any stored information.

Does anyone have any idea how this is possible? Feel free to request more information.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? Recent versions have introduced [stricter security policies](https://www.mozilla.org/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox.html).

Comment: This is using version 24.0. However the weird thing is that one time, FireFox works, and the other time, it's the browser that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this problem myself. 
I just use Safari instead of Chrome to access my Database.

Heard that it is because the time on the server is set before the time in your browser, this causes the browser not to create cookies needed for operation.
Some browsers can, some do not.

I have not yet tested this theory because I don´t know where to change the server time.

Comment: This could also be a time zone issue then. Make sure the time matches the time zone, also on your own computer; see https://time.is It's fine if the server says it's 8:15 AM in time zone UTC, while it's 2:15 AM in Mexico or 9:15 AM in Amsterdam (assuming no daylight saving time). That said, if cookies set an expiration, then that is a full timestamp based on the current server time; so that should never be a problem if the server is ahead of time, but could if it's behind. However, *all* browsers *should* reject cookies that have expired when they receive them...